# Text on left and button on right in one line

Tags: html, jsp

Please, Help me with this..
I want Text and Button on single line but text on the left side and button on the right side..

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <h2>Welcome ${faculty.getFirstName()}</h2>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;float: right">
    <button>Log Out</button>
</div>
```

Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/vqat5kuu/1/

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: They are on the same line here (Viewing in chrome). The `h1` just have a big top margin. You can see it, if you add boder. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqat5kuu/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, try to give the h2:.

```
margin:0;
```

somtimes elemnts get margin from parents or something.
i've chekced it, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Don't use h2 because it is rendered as a block element, use

```
span
```

for text instead.